# Cant access puma in browser

Tags: vagrant, puma

I am attempting to visit a site set up using vagrant. It is a puma server and I usually run it with:

```
rails s -p 3001 -b 0.0.0.0
```

This returns the following output:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3001
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Puma 2.12.2 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3001
```

Once this is complete I would usually access it via:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3001/
```

however it is no longer working. It has been some time since I last worked in this environment so I cannot remember what the issue could be. Here is my vagrantfile also:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3001, host: 3001
end
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you confirm it works from the VM (running curl,wget ...) ?

Comment: When i run curl http://127.0.0.1:3001 I get 

`DEPRECATION WARNING: You didn't set "secret_key_base". Read the upgrade documentation to learn more about this new config option. (called from validate_secret_key_config! at /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:530)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-18 09:57:06 +0000
Processing by UserSessionsController#new as */*
  DashboardUser Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "redacted"
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 452ms (ActiveRecord: 54.4ms)`

Comment: can you add `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080` and point to 127.0.0.1:8080 from your host. also if you work with chrome try localhost:8080 / 3001 or change your browser

Comment: Added `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3001, host: 3001` which worked. Stupidly I started playing around with my configuration before saving it somewhere to revert. Anyway thanks for the help. Pointed me in the right direction.